# Selenium, Python, Can't Click Button by Checking the Table Items Name

Tags: python, macos, google-chrome, selenium

I am trying to improve my `Selenium` skills and for this task, I try to click a button the way that chooses it by table elements name.

For example, in this case, I want to locate `EB Trial 2` then click the `import` button which is related to that.

```
<tr ng-repeat="event in bcEvents" class="ng-scope">
            <td>
                <div class="dib fxac">
                    <i class="icon-event fs32 text-light-blue mr15"></i>
                    <div class="event-inner">
                        <a href="" class="link link-underline db ng-binding">EB Trial2</a>
                        <span class="db fs-small text-light-blue ng-binding">11/15/2016</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td ng-switch="bc_source">
                <!-- ngSwitchWhen: 2 --><div ng-switch-when="2" class="ng-scope">
                    <a href="" ng-click="import_bc_event(event)" class="btn btn-icon btn-orange">
                        <i class="icon icon-eventbrite-icon"></i> Import
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- ngSwitchWhen: 8 -->
                <!-- ngSwitchWhen: A -->
                <!-- ngSwitchWhen: 9 -->
                <!-- ngSwitchWhen: B -->
            </td>

            <!-- ngIf: bc_source != 2 -->
        </tr>
```

I try to reach it by `XPath` but it didn't work

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(),'EB Trial2')]/preceding-sibling::td[1]").click()
```

I can't figured it out how to do it

Can anybody help me about this ?

Comment: Please post the code you are using and what errors, etc. you are encountering.

Comment: I try to reach it by XPath but it didn't work driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(),'EB Trial2')]/preceding-sibling::td[1]").click() like this. I can't figured it out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to locate EB Trial 2 then click the import button which is related to that

You should try using `xpath` as :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[descendant::a[text()='EB Trial2']]/following-sibling::td//a[normalize-space(.)='Import']").click()
```

Comment: Btw I try to wait until the button is clickable with this code element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"")) but it gives me unknown error: Element is not clickable at point lots of times